# LINQPad, Util.RawHtml and Results Pane seem to change behavior of HREF and Uri.EscapeDataString

Tags: linqpad

I have the following code:

```
var data = "LINQPad+Util.RawHtml";
Util.RawHtml( string.Format( "<a href=\"http://localhost/test?data={0}\">Test</a>", System.Uri.EscapeDataString( data ) ) ).Dump();
```

If I just click the 'Test' link rendered in the Results pane, the url in the browser is:
http://localhost/test?data=LINQPad+Util.RawHtml

If I right click the link and say 'Open in New Window' the url in the browser is:
http://localhost/test?data=LINQPad%2BUtil.RawHtml

The second method is the correct one (I think - as the resulting url in my ASP MVC application works correctly).  If I view source of the Results pane, save the file locally and open with a browser and then simple click the link, it again shows:
http://localhost/test?data=LINQPad%2BUtil.RawHtml

So is there something wrong with the Results pane that it massages (or rather URL decodes HREFs before it opens a new browser?